# create a custom widget dynamically flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i create a custom method

```dart
Widget textinputPassnger() {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Container(
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 20),
        width: 250,
        height: 30,
        child: Card(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          elevation: 5,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Passnger Number $passngerNumber",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Text(
        "Passanger Name",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15,
      ),
      Inputfield(
        controller: _controllers[passngerNumber],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Text(
        "Mobile",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15,
      ),
      Inputfield(
        controller: mobileTextController,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Text(
        "Reservation number",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15,
      ),
      Inputfield(
        controller: reservationNumberTextController,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Text(
        "Ticket number",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 15,
      ),
      Inputfield(controller: ticketNumberTextController),     
    ],
  );
}
```

and When the button is pressed, a widget is created

```
textinputList.add(textinputPassnger())
```

inside this list

```
List<Widget> textinputList = [textinputPassnger()];
```

my problem how do I get to the text that was created when I press the button?
Is there a ready-made package that facilitates this work?
ty

Comment: Depends on the type of controller you are using. `reservationNumberTextController.text` might do the trick. One probably should not store Widgets in a list but a model / data / controllers and then render a list of widgets based on the model / data / controllers. Showing more code would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.